# Any workaround for : context.sleep.Where(o=>o.clientDateTime.TimeOfDay>new TimeSpan(18,0,0)).ToList();

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net

This statement doesnot work in Entity Framework

```
context.sleep.Where(o=>o.clientDateTime.TimeOfDay>new TimeSpan(18,0,0)).ToList();
```

Please suggest me a workaround.

Exception Message:

> The specified type member 'TimeOfDay' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

Comment: "Doesn't work" isn't an error description!

Comment: The specified type member 'TimeOfDay' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A workaround would be to use this:

```
WHere(o=>o.clientDateTime.Hour >= 18)
```